# Request.Url and ReferrerUrl 

Tags: c#, url

Suppose our site has got a request from a **google** search result. In that case when i am taking **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()** and **HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()**, what should be the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i think `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` returns your actual website's url

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

returns `the previous request that linked to the current URL.`
so you got request from a google search result if its first request and next is your webpage...

that wat i think...

Answer (score 3):

Request.URL would give the URL information about the current page, where URL referrer would be the link of the previous page which requested the current page.